# Replacing a value in a data frame with a random value (NA exists)

Tags: r

Consider following data frame then replace all ones with random values (not the same).

```
a<-  c(rep(1,5),rep(NA,6))
b<-  c(rep(NA,5),rep(1,6))    
dat<- cbind(a,b)
dat

       a  b
 [1,]  1 NA
 [2,]  1 NA
 [3,]  1 NA
 [4,]  1 NA
 [5,]  1 NA
 [6,] NA  1
 [7,] NA  1
 [8,] NA  1
 [9,] NA  1
[10,] NA  1
[11,] NA  1
```

#### Initial solution:

```
dat[dat==1 & !is.na(dat)]<-sapply(dat[dat==1 & !is.na(dat)], function(x) runif(1))
dat
              a         b
  [1,] 0.2334880        NA
  [2,] 0.8845379        NA
  [3,] 0.6637202        NA
  [4,] 0.2647029        NA
  [5,] 0.3889980        NA
  [6,]        NA 0.7698119
  [7,]        NA 0.4197624
  [8,]        NA 0.4120188
  [9,]        NA 0.8229534
 [10,]        NA 0.7535820
 [11,]        NA 0.4248589
```

#### And the second part: Save it to a new variable (`dat` variable remains unchanged)

```
newdat<- some code
```

Comment: Removing gratuitous embolding and avoiding the use of "cute" phrases & smileys may prove fruitful in getting more folks to render aid in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just multply by the `runif` as any value multiplied by `NA` returns `NA` while those multiplied by 1 returns the value

```
dat * runif(length(dat))
#             a          b
# [1,] 0.03501729         NA
# [2,] 0.73306529         NA
# [3,] 0.61079151         NA
# [4,] 0.79167747         NA
# [5,] 0.52095513         NA
# [6,]         NA 0.01196499
# [7,]         NA 0.45024003
# [8,]         NA 0.79531526
# [9,]         NA 0.82090048
#[10,]         NA 0.63468136
#[11,]         NA 0.83556364
```

Comment: would you please answer newly added part?

Answer (score 2):

We could get the indices of values where value is 1 and then replace those with random values using `runif`.

```
newdat <- dat
inds <- which(newdat == 1)
newdat[inds] <- runif(length(inds))



#                a         b
# [1,] 0.589059571        NA
# [2,] 0.585798106        NA
# [3,] 0.268349643        NA
# [4,] 0.616500063        NA
# [5,] 0.007331229        NA
# [6,]          NA 0.6506516
# [7,]          NA 0.7121793
# [8,]          NA 0.8127495
# [9,]          NA 0.7795301
#[10,]          NA 0.7475504
#[11,]          NA 0.7159547
```

Comment: would you please answer newly added part?

Comment: @imi if you want to keep `dat` unchanged. You can copy it first to new variable `newdat <- dat ` and then run the code.